# When writing a program for an interview and discussing time complexity, is it a good idea to discuss the necessity for optimization?

Tags: software-industry

I may have fricked up my interview.

Per the interviewer's instructions, I wrote a program that ended up taking O(n^3) time. The interviewer then asked if I could improve my algorithm to O(nlogn) time. I did not see a way to do so and answered as much. THEN, I mentioned how if this were a professional setting, I wouldn't be concerned with optimization unless the algorithm was so poorly optimized as to cause the program to violate time constraints.

The interviewer, fortunately, kind of engaged me in discussion regarding that point and seemed to understand where I'm "coming from," so to speak.

Was it a mistake to discuss the necessity of optimization, or not? Might it have worked in my favor?

Comment: I don't see anything out of ordinary or any immediate "no-hire" flags in your description of the interview. Diving into topic brought up by interviewee is a reasonable strategy as there is a good chance that it is the topic interviewee is passionate about and conversation would give more ideas about their working/communication style compared to "just write some code".

Comment: He wanted to know if you knew your computer science.  Choosing the right algorithm is important when you go to very large datasets.  An n-logn algorithm typically solve a data set by splitting the input data in half, solve each half recursively, and merge the two results back. Look at mergesort.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: TBH, if that were the case, I'd probably just Google an algorithm (or, better yet, the code to implement said algorithm)

Comment: @moonman but how will you search for it if you don’t know it even exists?

Comment: O(n^3) is something that gets you into trouble even with a powerful computer. O(n^3) _will_ violate time constraints. With O(n^2) you can bet that you'll get enough complaints from some customers that you have to fix it.

Comment: I actually had that happening, when a product used an algorithm that was usually running in linear time, but if you arranged the data it processed in a highly unusual way, it would take O(n^3). And then we had a customer who did exactly that, making the software unusable.

Comment: Well, I have seen colleagues worrying *days* about how to optimize their algorithm and when I asked what it was used for, it turned out that due to real world physical constraints in the warehouse where they would use the program and the algorithm, n would never be larger than 3. It's hard to find an algorithm bad enough to mess that up and it's certainly not worth worrying about O notations then. "Algorithm" does not neccessarily mean lots of data. It just mean it's easier to have a formula than to make single cases.

Comment: @gnasher if the input size is guaranteed to be small enough n^3 will be fine.  Quicksort quickens a lot by optimizing small cases.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Small enough = constant time. Quicksort runs in O (n log n) and I have lots of software where an O (n^3) sort would be totally unusable.

Comment: @nvoigt Well, that's bad judgment. As it happens, just yesterday I wrote some O(n^2) code for a case where n ≤ 10 is guaranteed, so that's fine. But O(n^3) you really must _know_ that n is small.

Comment: @gnasher729  Quicksort may run in O(n^2) for pathetic data and a naive pivot element chooser.   O(n log n) is if the pivot element always splits the interval looked at in two equal halves.

Answer (score 11):

> Was it a mistake to discuss the necessity of optimization, or not?

It wasn't a mistake.

> Might it have worked in my favor?

It might well have.

I think your answer is exactly what I would want to hear if I were the hiring manager. IMHO, too many candidates talk about computer science and theory, while too few take a real-life business viewpoint.

Well done.

Comment: Exactly. If it meets the spec then it's good enough. After that, more time spent optimizing is time wasted which could have been applied to other business needs.

Comment: I would consider the situations where an interviewee wrote a program and didn't know there was a solution that would scale better, and wrote a program and deliberately chose one that didn't scale well different, and I would like to know which one this was.   The reasoning "good enough" needs background information.

Comment: A typical distinction in a real world scenario would be whether you need to do that computation just once or whether you (or even some customer) needs to do it over and over again. In the first case any time spend on optimization after you got the result is essentially wasted.

Comment: +1 - I also agree with a slightly skewed take. As an interviewer, once I was certain you had the technical skills to do the task I'd then move on to understanding if you were able to understand a different viewpoint, put your assumptions into words and defend them and were open to feedback, or at least questions, about your work. I'm sure if it hadn't been optimization the OP would have had a different but similar question. So any open answer would have suited.

Comment: Elon Musk actually said it best. People mistakenly try to optimize things that should've been removed. If it is stupid and actually shouldn't be there, optimizing it helps nobody.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I follow the philosophy of: "First get it done, then get it done FAST." First priority is to write a program that works. If the program is too slow, then optimize as necessary.

Comment: @moonman239 How much time do you expect to pass after you write the program before it is found out that it is "too slow" in production?  How much time do you expect the project manager to put aside to rewrite your code late in the process?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen To be honest, I don't know. In all my years of coding experience, such a concern has never come up. I guess I would ideally know approximately how scalable the program needs to be before we even begin to design it. If my manager/client tells me they expect 20 users to use the program, I'm designing with that assumption in mind. If it turns out 100,1000,or 100,000 people are using it and are finding it too slow, then we can revisit the design.

Comment: @moonman239 "In all my years of coding experience" - that got me curious.  Your profile says "My declared major in college is Computer Science." - does this mean that you are or was still in college now or when your profile was created seven years ago?  You also said "Since I would have no former employing company" in https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/67335/873 five years ago.  Could you share what your experience is?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sure. I have about 8-10 years of experience working in mobile application development, some of which was as an intern. I never concerned myself with making optimizations unless there was something obviously wrong, and - in any case - my clients were perfectly happy with the final result. My philosophy comes from a college professor. Many profs at my university have industry experience.

Comment: My thinking is: There should always be a compelling business reason to perform an optimization. If a single algorithm takes a computer out of commission for a day, for example, then yeah - maybe we should try a different algorithm. But if the program takes 10 seconds out of a 12-hour day, and the user is patient enough, then don't bother (unless maybe you're doing something extremely stupid)

Comment: @moonman with 8-10 years of experience I would not worry about the interview.  Your resume is most likely sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

When I was still interviewing, I would often ask similar questions. I state a problem, asks you to describe an algorithm, and if the running time isn't optimal, first ask you whether you can see a way to improve then, followed by some discussion about complexities.

"I wouldn't be concerned with optimization unless it violates time constraints" is missing the point. Multiple ways.

First, it's not answering the question. It's an interview. I want to know what you know about time complexities and scaling. You're deflecting the question.

Second, it gives the impression you're not concerned about looking ahead. You give the impression you just want an assignment with clearly defined constraints, and anything with fits is good. But if I have to pick between someone who writes code which needs to be revisited next year when the project grows by 25% versus someone who writes code which works till the project has grown by 250% before it needs to revisited, I pick the latter one.

Third, there's a difference between a bad algorithm (O (n^3) vs O (n log n)) and code which isn't optimized. A cubed algorithm will scale poorly, no matter how it's optimized.

Fourth, if you are only concerned about performance once time constraints have been violated, you're too late. That's the moment the company will start losing money.

Now, if you were interviewing with me, and you would have made such a remark, but went on and answered the question, I wouldn't hold it against you. But don't go on about it -- the interview is only so long, and I do need to know what you know about time complexities, and how well you can judge them.

Comment: This is spot on. The remark was okay, but it's no substitute for actually answering the question.

Comment: Exactly.  You don't lose points for saying this.  You don't lose points for not getting the optimal solution on the first try.  But I'm giving you this test to see your CS skills, I want you to try and find a better answer.  Depending on the level of the job and the skills you show in getting there the O(n^3) may or may not be good enough to pass.

Comment: +1 for this. Way too often on SE Workplace people go the route of "that must have been a trick question to see if you refuse it". I've never seen or heard of that in reality; assume the question they asked is the one they wanted answered.

Comment: ""I wouldn't be concerned with optimization unless it violates time constraints" is missing the point. Multiple ways." I told the interviewer that I didn't know how to optimize the algorithm. If I ever had the knowledge I needed to optimize that algorithm, that knowledge is now gone. I did the Software Engineering track in college, so I didn't really touch data structures & algorithms after my first year (although I still know some basics)

Answer (score 1):

I, too, see nothing damning in your response.  You wrote an algorithm that presumably worked.  You were asked if you knew how to improve it and you honestly said, "no."  You then said that you would only strive to improve the performance of the algorithm if you actually observed that it *needed* to be improved.  ("If it ain't broke, don't fix it.")  All of these answers are entirely defensible.

Answer (score 0):

In general, its great idea, only I would suggest another approach next time.

Instead, ask what kind of *n* you should expect right at the beginning. If asked why, give the talk. But you are likely to be told "any/unknown" anyway.

Then remember the interview is more focused on how do you think rather than if you can solve the task (well, mostly).
Given the situation, I would say something along the lines of "I can't think of anything better at the moment, were it real situation, I would first check for *n* ranges and business needs and **if needed**, probe the internet and/or consult my colleagues"

The talk:

I wouldn't talk about time-constraints directly, that sounds like you aim for the bare-minimum effort; instead talk about real usage - like whether the code is part of UI vs nightly ran backend job. Show you understand business impact - if n is low and will stay so, it may not be worth implementing something more complex. If it is low now, but expected to rise in the future, talk about prioritization, technical debt, even premature optimization (e.g. I can spend two days on something, that may become a problem in 6 months or on something that brings value now).

Note:

> The interviewer then asked if I could improve my algorithm to O(nlogn)
> time.

In my experience, the interviewers tend to ask "Can you think of any way to improve your solution" anyway, but in this case it is likely the interviewer knew it can be done in O(n log n).